# Android javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a file using the following code:

```
    Uri targURI = Uri.parse("content://xxxx/yyy.txt");
    try {
        InputStream content = getContentResolver().openInputStream(targURI);
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line1;
        String text = "";
        while ((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
            text+=line1;
        }
        Log.i("FILE ENCRYPTED", text);
        String DECRYPTED = "";
        DECRYPTED = decrypt(text);
        Log.i("FILE DECRYPTED:", DECRYPTED);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String decrypt(String paramString) throws Exception {
        String md5_pin1 = "";
        String md5_pin = MD5(md5_pin1);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(md5_pin.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
        byte[] paramString1 = Base64.decode(paramString.getBytes(), 0);
        byte[] paramstring2 = cipher.doFinal(paramString1);
        String decoded = new String(paramstring2, "UTF-8");
        return decoded;
    }

@NonNull
public static String MD5(String paramString) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    digest.update(paramString.getBytes());
    byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    int i=0;
    while( i < messageDigest.length) {
        String str = Integer.toHexString( messageDigest[i] & 0xFF );
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            hexString.append("0");
        }

        hexString.append(str);
        i += 1;
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}
```

as it is showed the file is accessed using a content provider, and stored in a String variable, and actually the correct string value is stored (encrypted data).
The way to decrypt it is to get a seed (empty space in this case), and then use MD5 digest, then use that value to encrypt/decrypt the cleartext.
However whenever the code reaches:  String decoded = new String(paramstring2, "UTF-8"); the error message: pad block corrupted is thrown. 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where and how is the encryption done?

Comment: it is done when it hits the decrypt method.

Comment: I am not asking where the Exception occurs. I am asking where and how the encryption takes place. Post the encryption code and we can see if it matches the decryption code.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using default padding for cipher as it may be different on different environment.

Try the following code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Also use the same padding for encrypting the file.

You can use the following methods:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivParams);
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] ivByte = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    IvParameterSpec ivParamsSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivParamsSpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
}
```

Comment: got now: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be specified in CBC mode. I am pretty sure this enc/dec program does not use IVs. Also i can't change the encryption process, I am trying just to decrypt the file. And I am sure Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); is the only in use

Comment: If you cannot change the encryption process, you should at least know how it has been encrypted and decrypt it in the same way. And again, you should not rely on the default mode.

Comment: Nabin, thanks for the advice, however my objective is just to decrypt the file. I know Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES") is in use

Comment: OK, did you try the new edited code for decryption with `IvParameterSpec`?

Comment: the app does not use IvParameterSpec

Answer (score -1):

This was not a problem related to coding.
Please disregard this question